# what's the font Apple use for number keyboard in ios7?

Tags: iphone, ios

what's the font Apple use for number keyboard in ios7?[image]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about identifying a font, not programming.

Answer (score 9):

It's Apple's own version of **Helvetica Neue Ultra Light (or Ultralight)**. I don't think anyone has the official name yet.

An additional thing to note is that the font dynamically changes depending on its size. As shown in the slide below, the **iOS 7's Dynamic Type** (shown in the middle) increases the boldness as font gets smaller and decreases boldness as font gets bigger. Hence, the font is a mix of both Helvetica Neue Ultralight and Helvetica Neue. Apple did this because Neue Ultralight is harder to read in small sizes, while regular Neue is heavy in larger sizes.
Please check out this link [iOS 7 fonts](http://typographica.org/on-typography/beyond-helvetica-the-real-story-behind-fonts-in-ios-7/).

[image]